How to use union of multiple inputs in Graphql
I want have multiple input types in actionMeta as you cannot directly use a union in the input is ,there a way in GraphQL to do it?
input CreateActionInput {
  name: String
  order: Int!
  status: ActionStatus!
  workspaceId: String!
  type: ActionTypes!
  actionMeta: ActionMetaInput
}

union ActionMetaInput = SendEmailInput | AddToCalendar
input SendEmailInput {
  emailId: String
}

input AddToCalendar {
  date: String
}

I got this suggestion from GPT, but I feel it complicates the input for the client as there can be nesting in specific action types like AddToCalendar  or any new type incoming.
input CreateActionInput {
  name: String
  order: Int!
  status: ActionStatus!
  workspaceId: String!
  type: ActionTypes!
  actionMeta: ActionMetaInputObject
}

input ActionMetaInputObject {
  meta: ActionMetaInput
}

